# How to read and match certain values in an online XML file through Python?

Tags: python

I have a massive online hosted XML file that has hundreds of nested XML files in it. I wish to do the below:

1. Parse any nested XML (could be multiple files) if a certain condition is met i.e. country/language.
2. Read through the parsed files to find a certain input URL by the user.
3. If the URL matches then throw a True output.
4. when URL is matched, return the XML file name it is found in.

I am actually stuck at 1st point in the list above. Tried urllib, elementtree but couldn't move ahead with further steps. Any help to take the first step and then I'll be able to share my code too!

Comment: how is the country and language stored / represented?

Comment: they look something like below:

/nested-file/category-en-AE_1.xml
/nested-file/category-en-AE_2.xml

Comment: If you can give an example, you can understand what you want more clearly. For example, a user input, the names and contents of the XML files you have, and the result returned.